# Problem in JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, serialization, jfilechooser

> I want to use JfileChooser to choose a file and writeObject to the selected file or readObject from the selected file. I have serialize my class but I don't know how to serialize this **MetalFileChooserUI**? Or do I need to do it? Thank you very much.

[smiliar error message to mine](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6215611)

Can someone help me to find a solution to it? Thank you.
My Error message:

> java.io.NotSerializableException: javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalFileChooserUI
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
> at javax.swing.ArrayTable.writeArrayTable(Unknown Source)
> at javax.swing.ActionMap.writeObject(Unknown Source)
> at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor11.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(Unknown Source)
> at javax.swing.JComponent.writeObject(Unknown Source)
> at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(Unknown Source)
> at javax.swing.JList.writeObject(Unknown Source)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Window.writeObject(Unknown Source)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Window.writeObject(Unknown Source)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
> at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
> at ver_2.sudoku_GUI.actionPerformed(sudoku_GUI.java:90)
> at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
> at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
> at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
> at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
> at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
> at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
> at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
> at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: What exactly do you want to serialize ? The JFileChooser object itself ?

Comment: Thanks guys, maybe I didn't describe the problem clearly, I use the JFileChooser to get the file I want to save to, then use ObjectOutputStream to write the class which I have serialized to the selected file. The error occurs, I just wondering why it is happening, because the ObjectOutputStream has nothing to do with the JFilechooser. I would like to try **transient** first. Thanks Costi Ciudatu. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not actually want to serialize the JFileChooser but you simply have a reference to it in some class of yours (that you need to serialize) make that reference `transient` so the serialisation process will simply ignore it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you would want to serialize a file chooser as what would be the sense in this?  I think that your best bet is to not serialize the gui portion of a program but rather the data held in the model (assuming an MVC structure) -- unless you have requirements that we need to know about.